# Copy rows from one DataFrame1 to DataFrame2 when DF1.col1 == DF3.col1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a 3 datasets. My_tracks, All_tracks, and final_df.

My_tracks - 2544,3

All_tracks - 114000, 19

final_df = new dataframe

I want final_df to have all the songs of my_tracks with shape of all_tracks

required final_df.shape is (n,19) when my_tracks.Track == all_track.track_name append final_df.append(all_tracks

IMAGES OF THE DATAFRAMES
[All_track](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wN5Qy.jpg)
[My_track](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n2no.jpg)

Following is the query that I tried

```
final_df = all_tracks[all_tracks.track_name.isin(my_tracks.Track)]
```

or

```
for i in my_tracks.Track:
    if i in all_track.track_name:
        final_df.append(all_track.loc[])
```